# Debug an orchestration in biztalk 2010

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

I'm making an orchestration to send data from one SQL Server DB to another one. I'm able to receive the data but unable to send it to the other DB. I made a send port to test what I'm getting as an input. I got to know that I'm not getting the right data from the source schema. I have tested the map from visual studio 2010, and it is working fine. But i'm getting following error in event viewer:

```
The adapter "SQL" raised an error message. Details "HRESULT="0x80040e14"     
Description="SQLOLEDB Error Description: Empty update, no updatable rows found  Transaction aborted "

 <Root xmlns:ns00="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-updategram">
      <?MSSQLError HResult="0x80040e14" Source="Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" Description="SQLOLEDB Error Description: Empty update, no updatable rows found  Transaction aborted "?>
 </Root>".
```

I want debug the orchestration. How can I do so?

Comment: Jonatthan Wu has some info on this error here - http://biztalkshow.blogspot.com/2005/02/how-to-use-updategram-to-update.html. However if you are in a position to use the WCF SQL adapter you will find it a lot more rewarding - http://connectedthoughts.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/wcf-sql-versus-the-old-sql-adapter/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via the admin console you can view the suspended orchestration and set break points.  The future runs of the orchestration will hold at the break point and again through the admin console you can attach to the orchestration and view information such as message content.

Comment: Thanks yieldvs I have been able to identify the mistake through debugging. Debugging makes life a lot easier!